# Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LinkExtractorParseException

Tags: jmeter

How to solve following error in jmeter:

```
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LinkExtractorParseException
```

Comment: you need to provide more details as full error and what's you request

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's useful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would guess an exception occurred parsing HTML text to extract links for Download resources features.

Ensure you use last jmeter 4.0 version and set:

> httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true